# How to merge 2 scripts (read URL and output array)?

Tags: foreach, merge, show, document.write, geturl

I have 2 scripts that I cannot seem to figure out how to merge.

- **In script #1** - I read a URL and output the returned value(s).  Usually just one.
- **In script #2** - I write the results from one or more array(s) into lists.

**SCRIPT #1:**

```
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
    var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
        var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
        if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
            return KeyValuePair[1];
        }
    }
}

document.write(GetUrlValue('val1'));
document.write("<br>");
document.write(GetUrlValue('val2'));  //only used if needed for a second list
document.write("<br>");
```

**SCRIPT #2:**

```
function ShowResults(value, index, ar) {
    document.write(" • " + value);
    document.write("<br />");
}

showCons = 'test this con';
showCaPS = 'caps...test this also';
showComm = 'test comm';
showDES = 'dis des, testing';

var divCons = [[showCons], [showCaPS], [showComm]];
var divCaPS = [[showCaPS], [showComm], [showCons], [showDES]];
var divComm = [[showComm], [showCons]];
var divDES = [[showDES]];

    document.write("Cons header <br>");
    divCons.forEach(ShowResults);
    document.write("<br>");

    document.write("CaPS header <br>");
    divCaPS.forEach(ShowResults);
    document.write("<br>");
```

I am not sure how in SCRIPT 1 if I pull a ?val1=cons, or whatever, that I could then tie that to the SCRIPT 2 and display the "var divCons" as a header with the 3 show### bullet points, or use val1=caps and show the 4 caps related show### bullets.  And, then if a second set of information was needed to show, then just use the val2, and set that to whatever other value, like comm or des.

In short, instead of using the "**document.write(GetUrlValue('val1'));**" to output a value on the page, I need that same output value to be used as a variable that can trigger the "**divCons.forEach(ShowResults);**."

Be nice to me please, I am not a coder.  This task is just falling on me because our core dev. team is currently not able to handle this work.  Thanks in advance. :)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT!!!!  :D

I added a "if (GetUrlValue('val1') == 'cons') {" statement for each case, and that seems to tie this together.

Thanks.